# Warning: Unreachable code , using funtion component (Arrow function) in Reactjs 18

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-18

I created a function component and return JSX in react 18, but I was getting a strange warning; that "Unreachable code"

```
const Header = () => {
  return 
    <div className="header">
        <div className="container">
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>;
  
    
};

export default Header;
```

I was thinking it happened because of the missing parenthesis "()" but when I added it

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
       <div className="header">
        <div className="container">
            <h1>hello world!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>;
  ) 
    
};

export default Header;
```

And the error I got was

Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (8:10)
')' expected.
Declaration or statement expected.

Answer (score 1):

That was because I added an unexpected ";" after my JSX When I removed it, It worked

```
const Header = () => {
  return 
    <div className="header">
        <div className="container">
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div> 
  
    
};

export default Header;
```

or

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
       <div className="header">
        <div className="container">
            <h1>hello world!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  ) 
    
};

export default Header;
```

I only removed the ";" semicolon after the JSX in the return statement

Comment: Is it solves your problem?